# hyperlink is not generating while sending email from galaxy s2 v 4.0 only: android

Tags: android

I am able to send mail and share a link text in all devices if they are below v 4.0 , but while I am sending email using the same code I am not getting clickable link on my email from galaxy s2 device , I am wondering why this is happening with only some of devices..my code for sending email with hyper link text are given below:

```
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        String aEmailList[] = { "" };
        String aEmailCCList[] = { "" };
        String aEmailBCCList[] = { "" };

        emailIntent
                .putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, aEmailList);
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_CC, "");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_BCC, "");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
            subject);
        emailIntent.setType("text/html");  

        emailIntent.putExtra(
                android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"" + linkUrlhere
                        + "\">Check out what I posted</a>"));
        mainContext.startActivity(emailIntent);
```

Comment: where can you see that your link is not clickable? In your compose activity?

Comment: no , in my mail inbox i have tested it..

Comment: Sure your inbox isn't detecting as spam or junk so its disabling HTML and links

Comment: @boardy..but i dont think so..because if email sending from some other device then its hyperlink is generating on same emailID ..